# How to add new music to my iPhone without losing my data?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music

My computer's hard drive broke down and I got it fixed. I now have no pictures, music or documents on my laptop. I had a USB key of several songs that I'd like to add to my iPhone but when I tried to put them on manually, iTunes wants to erase everything and add those ten songs. Is there a way I could add these songs without having to lose my data?

Comment: You need to expand this - is the hard drive just bare OSX. If so then iTunes is empty so what is it asking it can delete.

Comment: In a similar situation, I used [iExplorer](https://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) first to save what was on my iPhone. Then let iTunes do its thing and then manually added my saved songs to iTunes and synced again.  Sorry, It's been a while and I don't remember all the details however the main point I wanted to make was I was able to get everything off my iPhone first and saved separately from iTunes and in the end I didn't loose anything.  So you might want to check it out first. Note: I'm just a satisfied customer and I have no other affiliation with Macroplant, the developer of iExplorer.

Comment: I'll try what user3439894 said, Mark, my lap top hard drive is bare. What Itunes wants to erase is my iPhone when I'm trying to add new songs.